# SMA connectors minimum distance on PCB

Tags: pcb, layout, footprint, distance

I am designing a board, which will have several SMA connectors.

I am mainly concerned about the minimum distance between SMA connectors on the board, since we need also account for the size of the mounting tool that we need to use in order to mount the cable on the connector. Is there any general recommended min distance?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that it depends mainly on the size of the wrench you will use to connect and disconnect cables.

You will have to measure your wrench and work out what the distance needs to be to fit it between two adjacent nuts.

Answer (score 0):

We built RF switching units with 20 SMA connectors on a ~24 mm grid,. It was tricky installing all the cables but quite possible to reach any of them with a torque wrench, even one in the middle, with all the others installed.

For a single row, you could probably go even closer, maybe 21 mm?

Here's the [product brochure](http://www.alaris.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/brochures/DF-A0063%20Version%201.4.pdf) - no drawings but you can estimate the spacing from the dimensions.

Comment: thank you very much that was very helpful